# Sass Mixin Modulo not working correctly

Tags: css, loops, sass, mixins, modulo

I want to write a sass mixin that outputs a certain class every 5 steps from 1 to 100. But I can't get the modulo operator to work somehow. No class is created at all.

Here is my code

```
@mixin flex_percentage($className) {
    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
        @if $i % 5 != 0 {
            .#{$className}#{$i} {
                width: $i * 1%;    
            }
        }
    }
}
@include flex_percentage(p);
```

I also tried `$i mod(5)` but then it outputs all 100 classes.

I would like to have a output like

```
.p5 {
    width: 5%;
}
.p10 {
    width: 10%;
}
.p15 {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `@if $i % 5 != 0 {` should be like this:

```
@if $i % 5 == 0 {
```

The difference is between `!=` and `==` in the `if` clause. Your original code was actually outputting every class **except** those that were multiples of 5. If we change it to `==`, then only those classes which are multiples of 5 are output.

Live example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7550271

Comment: Thx Katie!! I was so busy with figuring out how to do modulos in sass, that I missed the obvious.. :)

Comment: No prob! Nice example - I think folks will benefit from it.